# Trouble creating correct variable using if statements in R

Tags: r

Recently I have started using R at my university and I'm experiencing some trouble with it.

I have two data files loaded in R. One file contains the starting and ending date and the name of a promotion and the other file contains the sales made on each day.

I want to make a list of promotion names as a column next to the sales data to eventually see if the type of promotion has an effect on the sales. So I want a list next to the number of sales that day telling what if and if so what sort of promotion was going on.

I started with:

```
sales.data$promoname <- ifelse(promotion.data$startdate < sales.data$date & promotion.data$enddate > sales.data$date, "0", promotion.data$promoname)
```

This gave me a list of the promotion names that repeats itself. Can you help me?

cheers!

Comment: Please show sample data from your data frame, along with the current output.

Comment: Makes sure your dates are all R Date-class. Use `merge` by date_var using "all.x"=TRUE for the first file. Then duplicate the promotion variable for as many days as you think it might have been effective, perhaps 3 or 4 days after it ends.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, this a sample of the data frame showing a promotion lasting for two weeks (https://drive.google.com/open?id=11QCDnJb7HrAX7pRqes8k31kYIEwXFic3).With this code: `sales$promotiontype <- ifelse(promo$PromotionStartdate <= sales$Day & promo$PromotionEnddate >= sales$Day 
                                      , promo$ActivityType, 0)` I wanted to create a column showing what promotion was going on. It created this output (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I4lekA4MBjYqnM-16zU9XiuhwdQ7TtwH/view?usp=sharing) its not always showing the desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The date is in the range and should show the type of promotion instead of zero.

Comment: @42- thanks for your reply! It helped. It stoped showing a repeating list of names and it now shows (occasionally) the right output

Comment: You could post some data and the code that occasionally succeeds and identify the problem areas. Then you could get better advice. The link to https://drive.google.com/open?id=11QCDnJb7HrAX7pRqes8k31kYIEwXFic3).With produces an error.